# How to receive and save image shared from another application

Tags: android, uri, filepath, sharing

```
if(intent.getType().startsWith("image/")){
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    imageView.setImageUri(imageUri);
}
```

Need to save this image in my applications data directory. Querying on content resolver returns path to only those image files which are already saved in the device. like,

```
private String getPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

but this does not works all the times because some of those image files are in private directories of the apps.
What to do to get read access to such files, so that copies of shared files can be written/saved for my application?
is there something wrong, that I should do some other way? kindly help, thank you.

Comment: Ha, just a typo comment: Querying and Queering are two very different things.  When you want to query something, you are "querying" it. "Queer" means something is weird or strange and has other, possibly offensive meanings in modern English. Sorry I couldn't provide any help to your actual problem :(

Comment: :D no problem, and thank you for correcting me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Queering on content resolver returns path to only those image files which are already saved in the device

It is far worse than that. This only works for a `Uri` from the `MediaStore`, and even then only in certain situations.

> What to do to get read access to such files, so that i can write copies of them for my application?

Step #1: Use `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri`

Step #2: Create a `FileOutputStream` for your desired copy

Step #3: Copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream` using standard Java file I/O

IOW, this is not significantly different than using `HttpURLConnection` to download a file from a URL.

Comment: okay, will opening an input stream work all times? or will there be some exceptional cases that i must take care of?

Comment: @AmanSharma: Well, there are always buggy clients, so you could always get an unusable `Uri`. And you may only have access to the content for a short while (as long as your process is running), so you would want to copy this data right away. Otherwise, this should be fairly solid.

Comment: before realizing that i can obtain inputStream directly on an uri, i was trying to fetch absolute path of the file in uri and then was writting that stuff using FileOutputStream.
now its all fine, Thank you.